# Extract value from xml in bash on a mac

Tags: regex, xml, bash, grep

I need to extract the name value (Product Finder) from this xml:

*File: config.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget id="com.abc.app" version="1.3.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" ios-CFBundleVersion="1.3.1.5" android-versionCode="5">
    <name>Product Finder</name>
    <description>
        Description
    </description>
</widget>
```

I've tried:

```
mles$ cat config.xml | grep '<name>'
    <name>Product Finder</name>
```

Some other answers suggest using `grep -oPm1 "(?<=<xmltag>)[^<]+"`, but that yields an error:

```
mles$ cat config.xml | grep -oPm1 "(?<=<name>)[^<]+"
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
[-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
[--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
[--null] [pattern] [file ...]
```

How can I get the name value? I need a solution without dependencies, so `grep` would be preferred

Comment: don't use regex to parse xml...

Comment: looks like you don't have GNU grep..  `grep -oPm1 "(?<=<name>)[^<]+" config.xml` would work on GNU grep and if PCRE is available

Comment: Use a tool like `xmlstarlet` or `xmllint`.

Comment: Fixed the example, sorry about the broken xml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep` only finds the line, you have to use an additional tool to extract the name, like `sed` (not an additional dependency):

```
grep '<name>' config.xml | sed "s@.*<name>\(.*\)</name>.*@\1@"
```

What `sed` does here is takes everything between `<name></name>` and substitutes the whole line with the found text between the tags

Comment: Why would you people recommend non XML aware tools when you can use `xmllint` or `xmlstarlet`

Comment: How would you remove the remaining whitespace?

Comment: @mles just added `.*` before and after the tags to remove whitespace tabs etc.

Comment: @Inian I wasn't actually aware that there are XML parsers available without installing additional packages. And since OP wanted no dependencies and used `grep` in his question I figured that `sed` is all OP needs in this case. Thanks for commenting, reading `man xmllint` right now :)

Comment: I'll accept this answer as I needed to finish my task yesterday and this worked. However I'm still interested in using xmllint for this - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43694722/extract-value-from-xml-file-with-namespaces-by-using-xmllint-in-bash

Answer (score 3):

Your `XML` isn't syntactically right. The [W3School XML validitor](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp) page says so,

> error on line 8 column 1.  Extra content at the end of the document

Because the header line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` is a [processing instruction](http://xmlwriter.net/xml_guide/xml_declaration.shtml) that identifies the document as being `XML`. All XML documents should begin with an `XML` declaration.

Also, `xmllint` should be built-into native `Mac OS X` bash by default in which you can just do

```
xmllint --xpath "/widget/name/text()" xml
Product Finder
```

The right formatting for your `XML` should have been

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget id="123" version="1.3.1">
   <name>Product Finder</name>
   <description>Description</description>
</widget>
```

Comment: You're right, I've edited the sample xml code. So xmllint was working fine, but I had omitted some of the attributes in the `<widget>` tag. With the attributes of the production config.xml file I get `XPath set is empty`. I guess this is a problem with the namespace?

Comment: @mles: you need share a snippet of the non-working `XML` for me to have a look at,

Comment: I have accept the solution with `grep` as I needed to finish my task yesterday and it worked. However I'm still interested in using xmllint for this. I've opened another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43694722/extract-value-from-xml-file-with-namespaces-by-using-xmllint-in-bash

Answer (score 1):

You should use a xml parser, like [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) for example.
Your **xml is invalid** and you should fix it, if you can't, use the following regex:

```
perl -n -e'/<name>(.*)<\/name>/ && print $1' file.xml
# Product Finder
```

---

Options:

```
-n                assume "while (<>) { ... }" loop around program
-e program        one line of program (several -e's allowed, omit programfile)
```

Comment: Why would you people recommend non XML aware tools when you can use `xmllint` or `xmlstarlet`

Comment: You're absolutely right,  but in this specific case, the xml is invalid and both `xmlstarlet` and `xmllint` will fail.

Comment: Fair enough, who needs a broken `XML` to work with on the first place? It should be fixed and once fixed the right tool should be suggested. :)

Comment: OP's move in mysterious ways!

Answer (score 1):

The following bash built-in will do the job but it's not an xml parser

```
while IFS=\> read -d\< -r tag value || [[ -n $tag ]]; do
    if [[ $tag == name ]]; then
        echo "$value";
        break;
    fi;
done < config.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the multiple delimiter feature of awk:

```
awk -F'[<>]' '/name.*name/{print $3}' config.xml
```