# Extract value from xml file with namespaces by using xmllint in bash

Tags: xml, bash, xml-namespaces, xmllint

I need to extract the name value (Product Finder) from this xml:

*File: config.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget id="com.abc.app" version="1.3.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" ios-CFBundleVersion="1.3.1.5" android-versionCode="5">
    <name>Product Finder</name>
    <description>
        Description
    </description>
</widget>
```

I've tried:

```
mles$ xmllint --xpath "/widget/name/text()" config.xml 
XPath set is empty
```

Which is probably because my `config.xml` file has other namespaces. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264134/xmllint-failing-to-properly-query-with-xpath/8266075#8266075) question I need to set the namespace by hand. So I've tried:

```
mles$ xmllint --shell config.xml / > setns x=http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets / > xpath /x:widget/name/text
```

There is no output on this one. Whats the correct syntax to extract the name value with xmllint?

Note: I already have a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43678029/extract-value-from-xml-in-bash-on-a-mac) with grep and sed, but I would like to use xmllint.

Comment: I can easily solve this with xmlstarlet

Comment: `sed 's/xmlns=".*"//g' config.xml | xmllint --xpath '/widget/name/text()' -` though I support Cyrus's answer :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your file uses namespaces (xmlns). To be independent of these, I suggest:

```
xmllint --xpath "//*[local-name()='widget']/*[local-name()='name']/text()" config.xml
```

Output:

```
Product Finder
```

Answer (score 3):

Notice that not only the element where the default namespace is declared resides in that namespace, but all descendant elements without prefix and without local default namespace implicitly inherit the default namespace from the ancestor. This means you also need to use the prefix `x` to reference `name` element since it inherits the default namespace from `widget` :

```
/ > xpath /x:widget/x:name/text()[1]
```